# Change searching from world level to first letter

Tags: taxonomy, search

Iwant to change the search filter from word level to first letter in terms when creating custom post.
How can change it ?
[image]

Comment: A lot more info is needed to be able to properly answer this.  How was this built?  Custom code, did you use a plugin, etc.  What does the code that runs that search look like, etc.  A screenshot of your custom post type doesn't provide the info needed to properly assist you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.